# Access Violation when running C++ desktop application on Citrix Metaframe

Tags: citrix

I have made a Windows application using C++ which runs with no error connecting to an Oracle database when installed in a real computer. When it runs on Citrix Metaframe it sometimes raises an "Access Violation" exception. Is there any rule or any special security action to be made for running a Windows C++ application on Citrix Metaframe ?

Comment: This is a topic for Stack Overflow. It's time to properly debug your application and find out where and why it's failing. The language the app is written in is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Access Violation usually means that an area of memory is accessed that may not be used. Citrix uses some special version of core dlls so bugs that are unnoticed in a normal environment may surface there.

The Access Violation error has addition information that is important and can be used to trace the bug.

Comment: That's a massive over simplification. Access Violation is a generic term which describes ALL access denied issues, not just memory related.

Comment: It says Access Denied on missing file system permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Run Sysinternals Process Monitor and look for any "Access Denied" messages when the error pops up.  It sounds like the user is missing appropriate file permissions.